# Using HTML attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am a beginner in javascript. I'm trying to add a function to generate new form elements using javascript, on a page that's generated in php.

The code works in creating new `<tr>, <td>, <input type="text">` html elements. However when I try to create buttons using css styles, I find that the styles are lost from the tags.

```
if(document.createElement) 
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var input = document.createElement("input");
// If NS is passed, should become NS[2] etc
input.id = field+"["+count+"]";
input.name = field+"["+count+"]";
input.type = "text"; //Type of field - can be any valid input type like text,file,checkbox etc.

var td=document.createElement("td");
var newContent = document.createTextNode("NS");
td.appendChild(newContent);

tr.appendChild(td);     
td=document.createElement("td");        
td.appendChild(input);
tr.appendChild(td);                 

var btnDel=document.createElement("a");
btnDel.class="btn btn-primary";
btnDel.onclick = "addField(\'nameservers\',\'NS\',10);" ;


var btnText=document.createElement("span");
btnText.class="btn-label";
btnText.innerHTML="Add";


btnDel.appendChild(btnText);        
td.appendChild(btnDel);
tr.appendChild(td);         
field_area.appendChild(tr);

}
```

The produced code shows:

```
<a><span>Add</span>
</a>
</td>
```

instead of what I expect:

```
<a onclick="addField('nameservers','NS',10);" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="btn-label">Add     
</span>
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the proper way of passing all html attributes using the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the on click**

Instead of trying to output this into the HTML, why not do this in pure Javascript, using the `addEventListener` method?

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {

    addField('nameservers','NS',10);

    }, false);
```

This approach is known as non-obtrusive Javascript, and it's actually quite a desirable attribute when developing a website.

**For the class**

As mentioned, use `className` and not `class`.

`class` usually precedes the declaration of as new class, and can't be used like an attribute, in the same way that you can't call a variable `var`.

Comment: About the first part of your explanation, is it just a best practise, or is using `element.onclick` actually wrong?

Comment: It's just best practise. It's not "WRONG". But in the future, when you want to work on just the javascript, you'll appreciate not having to go between your JS files and your HTML files because you've got all your JS references in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Use `className=` instead of `class=`. So it will be like:

```
btnDel.className="btn btn-primary";
```

It is because the `class` word is reserved word in JavaScript.